# What hovering means on button in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-event

I know that we can catch `Hovering event` in Android. So, I added a `Button` in my layout files.

What does `Hovering` mean in Android ?

- Press button and lifting finder from it?
- Put your finger on button (Impossible in Android). We can do it by connecting mouse through `OTP` cable. But why would a developer implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Also, on Android TV, it makes a lot of sense to Hover over an element, especially if it is supporting mouse pointer movement using TV remote

Answer (score 1):

There are devices which supports 'Air Gesture' and hovering can be used for that. Check this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.golgorz.hoveringcontrols&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for answering but i implemented the hovering in the same way as the question does (on Button). I wan not able to test it. How can I do that?

Also if you look the answer of `Gabe` (last answer) what does it mean? I do have a nexus 5. I am little bit confused about the implementation

Answer (score 0):

**IN some of the popular smart phone there is a way to dismiss call by just hovering the hand over the screen.**
`We can do it by connecting mouse through OTP cable. But why would a developer implement it?`
**The popularity of android id not limited to mobile devices alone there is TV,auto, variables etc. so with most of the tv you have universal remote which come with trackball also this is also used there** .